# Why can’t a private method in an interface be declared as final in Java?

Tags: java, kotlin

In Java 9 and later, we can declare private methods in interfaces. These private methods have a body and are mainly used to implement other methods within the interface or to hide implementation details. This helps to reduce code duplication and encapsulate the implementation of the interface. However, I noticed that private methods in interfaces cannot be declared as final. Why is this the case? What is the reason behind this restriction?

I asked GPT for an answer to this question, but it didn’t give me a clear answer.

Comment: In Java, `final` means you can't modify or override the method.  An interface is *designed* to be overridden.  It makes no sense.

Comment: Making private methods final makes no sense because they can't be overridden. It is allowed for historic reasons in classes, but when private methods were added to interfaces it was decided to simply not allow `final` for them.

Comment: @stdunbar You can't override private methods, and in Java you can define private methods in interfaces (e.g. for use in default methods).

Comment: My question is, since private methods themselves cannot be overridden, why can private methods be declared in an interface but not private final methods

Comment: Why can't you? Because [the language spec forbids it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4) "Note that an interface method may not be declared with protected or package access, or with the modifiers final, synchronized, or native." Why is it forbidden? Because it's not useful.

Comment: @ThePonderingQuestioner See my comment. Declaring a private method as final is nonsensical, so it was disallowed when they introduced it for interfaces. The fact you can declare a private method final in a class is a historic mistake which can't be fixed without potentially breaking existing code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not about interfaces. **All `private` methods are inherently final!**

This isn't just an observation - the JVM acts accordingly and e.g. hardcodes (skipping dynamic dispatch) when JITting calls to private methods the same way it does for `final` ones.

A private method **cannot be extended** because it is invisible to everything outside of the class.

There is one academic case where you *can* extend a private method: `private` doesn't quite mean 'invisible to everything outside this class'. It more closely means 'invisible to everything outside this source file', and in theory you can squeeze more than one class in a single source file. However, at the JVM level it doesn't work that way (if you squeeze more than 1 class into a source file, compiling that one `.java` file results in more than one `.class` file), and because of that, `javac` actually makes your method non-`private`, or makes non-private bridger synthetic methods instead. Allowing private methods to be `final` therefore makes no sense unless you know about that weirdness, which is probably not a good language feature.

`javac` fails to compile `private final void foo() {}` in an interface because it's nonsense. `javac` generates a warning when you write: `int x = (int) 5;` for the same reason: That code is nonsense. It's either stating the obvious to a ridiculous degree, or, more likely, it indicates the coder is confused about a concept. Same here: Marking a `private` method as `final` is either ridiculous (all private methods inherently always are, you're stating the obvious), or indicative of misunderstanding. Or a typo.

Assuming programmers aren't being ridiculous, it's correct to error (or possibly it is more correct to warn but that is a separate discussion).

Answer (score 1):

A private method by definition is final as it is not visible or accessible from any other class it can not be overridden which is the meaning of final. So, you don't need the ability to declare it final as it already is

Comment: @user16320675 - yes, but since there is no need ever to do that and it will not add anything to the code it makes sense that it is not allowed by the language so to reduce confusion. It is indeed not allowed, I tried to explain the reason why